# Where's django for loop value taken from?

Tags: python, django

When we are using `for loop` in django, where is that list come from?

The example in django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

doesn't give any explanation where's `athlete_list` came from. What thing is passing that array's values? I've go through django's official tutorial and managed to make it works. But, I don't understand about this one. (The tutorial, too, doesn't explain where it's come from).

Sorry for noobs question ...

Comment: It comes from the view, like all variables in a template context. This is nothing to do with for loops at all.

Comment: You need to go through the tutorial! The second (or third) page has information about this. Looks like you need to do the whole thing though!

Answer (score 1):

Your view has a context which it can use. Try reading http://www.pythoncentral.io/writing-simple-views-for-your-first-python-django-application/.

The essence, a view has looks like:

```
context = Context({
    'someVar': someValue
})
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

The template looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span>this is the value: {{someVar}}</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, this is the equivalent of "latest_question_list" in the section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something .

As told by the other answers, you should follow all the tutorial's pages. If you don't, you'll probably won't do the things the better and simpler way (and have your questions voted down).